# Count number of hits

Tags: cakephp

i'm developing simple cms application.

i want to integrate "number of hits" for some of the records, so when view of the record is showed in browser, hits field in table should be updated by 1.

in controller, i tryed with:

$data = array(  'Publication' => array(  'hits' => ' hits + 1')  );
  $this->Publication->save( $data );

... but no luck, since cake tryes to update field `hits` with value hits + 1.

can you tell me where i'm wrong, and how to incrementaly update field `hits`.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, i solved it

```
$this->Publication->updateAll(array('Publication.hits'=>'Publication.hits+1'), array('Publication.id'=>$id));
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`updateAll`](http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1000/Models#Saving-Your-Data-1031):

```
$this->Publication->updateAll(
    '`Publication`.`hits` = `Publication`.`hits` + 1',
    array('Publication.id' => $id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer doesn't work for cakephp 2.6.0, this works fine

```
$this->Product->updateAll(
   array('Product.hits' => 'Product.hits' + 1),
   array('Product.id' => $id)
);
```

Comment: This is invalid (Cake)PHP syntax. This cannot work!
You are adding 1 to a string. making the whole string "1". And the examples above should both work just fine.