# How to count the number of user downloads

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

This code for extract files dir and title.  The user download when clicked the file link.  I need to count then number of downloads.  How to do this with cakephp or php?

downloads_controller.php:

```
function index() {
    $this->set('downloads', $this->paginate());
}
```

downloads/index.ctp:

```
<?php
    $title = $download['Download']['title']; 
    // output filetitle 
    $filename = '/files/'.$download['Download']['filename']; 
    // output http://localhost/tet/files/un5titled0.rar
    echo $this->Html->link($title, $filename,array('escape' => false)); 
?>
```

Comment: See also: https://dave.autonoma.ca/blog/2023/11/12/php-download-hit-counter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function download($id = null) {
    $download = $this->Download->findById($id);
    $this->set(compact('download'));
    if(!empty($id)) {
        // increment the number of items downloads 
        $this->Download->save(array(
            'Download' => array(
                'id' => $id,
                'counts' => ($download['Download']['counts'] + 1)
            )
        ));
    }

    header('Location: http://localhost/tet/files/'.$download['Download']['filename']);
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

not this way i am afraid.

you either need to redirect from an action (which counts before redirecting) or use Media view to pass it through.
thats how I do it.
In the action you can then raise the count prior to sending the file.

Comment: check the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185049/count-number-of-hits - also see MedieView in cakephp docs for how to send files as download

Comment: i think is the best way to use MedieView in cakephp docs but i still dont know how to use it..the docs talk about useing the Media view to pull the file from a special folder not to count

Comment: well, you have to implement the first link, of course. write your own updateAll() query in this action before passing the vars to the view.

Comment: I find the book pretty self-explanatory on that: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html?highlight=media#MediaView

Comment: thanks mark..but it not contain any example to use media view to count downloads

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count downloads, you should create a function that serves those downloads and create a field in your database that increments downloads each time this function is called.. For example

Call the following function from your view passing the `$filename` and the `$id`

To try out at first use, taking ID=4 as one of the downloads ID in your DB

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/downloads/download/4
```

And Then your controller would be...

```
Class DownloadsController extends AppController{
    // All your other functions here

    function download($id = null){

        $this->Article->updateAll(
            array('Download.count' => 'Download.count+1'),
            array('Download.id' => $id)
        );

        $download = $this->Download->findById($id);

        $this->set('filename', $download['Download']['filename']);

        //$filename is an array that can then be used in your view to pass the file for download. to find out what is has you can use debug($filename) in your view
        }
}
```

Then you need to create a special layout so the browser knows that the request file is a download and you will also need to create a view for download.ctp. Basically when you click the file link on your page, it will call this function which will use its view to serve the file.

You can access the following which will provide some insight on what needs to be done..

[TUTORIAL LINK](http://edwardawebb.com/web-development/cakephp/serving-files-cakephp)

Comment: thanks caboone but it is not work..when download count not increase..and i cant understand how to handle $filename or $id in this function when someone download

Comment: I changed my function and provided more insight as well as a tutorial link

Comment: Caboone..this is great article..but This is not what I needed..idont need to save files in database..i save it into dirctory..i understand the point but But I miss understanding the relation between view and controller that make someone download from link like this http://www.yourdomain.com/downloads/download/4
not like this like this http://www.yourdomain.com/downloads/file.rar

Comment: Basically with `yourdomain.com/downloads/download/4` you are telling the controller to pass a filename to the view where the ID of that filename is 4. The controller will then look into the DB based on these conditions and return to the view the respective file. At this point I am not sure how to process the download, but you will most likely need to create a download.ctp layout where the <head> of it tells the browser that the file being served is a download.

Comment: thanks cabone i get the answer byself..you get me the the point..i write it here for everyone need this code

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of techniques, though in the simplest way, you can use a text file to do this.

Create a txt file and write 0 (zero) into it.

In your index function, read the content of your file.

```
$counter = file_read_contents('counter.txt');
```

Increase the read value by 1.

```
$counter++;
```

Write new value into file again.

```
file_put_contents('counter.txt', $counter);
```

So, it counts downloads and keep number in that file.

Comment: i have table called downloads..it has fields(id,filename,title)and i need to store data in new field called download_count

Comment: Well then, use an update sql like `update table_name set download_count=download_count+1 where id=selected_files_id`